# How do I lowercase the first letter of my title in php?

Tags: php

I want to lowercase the first letter of my title.

My code:

```
<?php echo $myRob->title; ?>
```

I understand that I need to use `lcfirst`, but what about `->title`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use from special character like "/", "#" and ... So,
Just put on a variable:

```
$title = $myRob->title;
echo lcfirst($title);
```

For special cases, you can use `regex` to find the first word and first letter of it and do `lcfirst` on it.

Comment: `echo lcfirst($myRob->title);` is prohibited?

Comment: `<?php echo lcfirst($myRob->title); ?>` @u_mulder not work! Cyrillic is used.

Comment: `echo lcfirst($myRob->title)` and `$title = $myRob->title;   echo lcfirst($title);` both are working.

Comment: This will not work with lcfirst because you use special characters. Maybe you can try it with css, so the browser will do it. use `::first-letter` and `text-transform:lowercase;`
The function itself is doing right if you would use A it would write a but not with special characters

Comment: @TobiasHH , thanks for the answer, I'll try to figure it out!